# JQwidgets Scheduler Angular Default To Today's Date

Tags: angular, scheduler, jqwidget

I am working with the scheduler and angular and would like to know if there is a way to make it so when the scheduler loads it defaults to today’s date. For instance, if we are defaulting to week view I would want it to start with the last Sunday and end with the next Saturday. For today’s date, April 2nd, I would want The first day displayed to be March 31st, and the last day, Saturday, to be April 6th. Any ideas? It seems to default the date displayed to the appointment furthest in time, whether that be an appointment that is a few days old or an appointment 4 years away. I don’t want to have to make people go find today’s date just because they made appointments years in advance. Any help?

Below is an example of me creating two appointments, when I open the scheduler it will open to the appointment in 2020. I want it to open to today's date.

```
  generateAppointments(): any {
    let appointments = new Array();
    let appointment1 = {
      id: "id1",
      description: "George brings projector for presentations.",
      location: "",
      subject: "Quarterly Project Review Meeting",
      calendar: "Room 1",
      start: new Date("2012-09-28 10:07 EDT"),
      end: new Date("2012-09-28 10:07 EDT")
    };
    let appointment2 = {
      id: "id1",
      description: "George brings projector for presentations.",
      location: "",
      subject: "Quarterly Project Review Meeting",
      calendar: "Room 1",
      start: new Date("2020-09-28 10:07 EDT"),
      end: new Date("2020-09-28 10:07 EDT")
    };

    appointments.push(appointment1);
    appointments.push(appointment2);
```

[image: Sample Calendar]

I have been reading through the Doc's but cannot find anywhere how to specify the default view's date. Anyone else run into this issue?